# What is Ghost Mode of Superuser Elite?

Tags: superuser

[Superuser Elite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su.elite) (paid) provides a premium-exclusive feature: Ghost Mode!

What is it?
As I haven't purchased it, I don't have option to test it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Superuser website](http://androidsu.com/elite/) explains it as such:

> **Ghost mode** – Hide Superuser from your app tray and home screen. With
>   ghost mode activated, the only way to launch it is by dialing a secret
>   code into the dialer. The default secret code is `*#*#787378737#*#*`,
>   but it can be set to whatever you want. Note that this feature will
>   probably be disabled if your device does not have a dialer (tablets
>   specifically).